# command "npx create-react-app project" not generating project

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

All of a sudden I started getting this error when I type 
*npx create-react-app project*

The error is : 
**Invalid "exports" main target "index.js" defined in the package config /home/swaraj/.npm/_npx/8451/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/is-promise/package.json**

Can anybody tell me what's this error and how to resolve it

Comment: It seems that your global install of `create-react-app` is having a problem. Try uninstalling and reinstalling it.

Answer (score 2):

This must mean that your package.json is broken.
I just had the same problem, and it fixed for me when I recreated/edited the package.json it is trying to access.

Type `yarn init -y` and read the package.json

Add the following lines:

```
"resolutions": {
    "is-promse": "2.1.0",
    "run-async/is-promise": "2.1.0"
  }
```

Afterwards do `yarn add --dev create-react-app` and then try to compile your reactjs application using:

`yarn create-react-app <PATH/APP-NAME>`

I would also recommend trying to manually remove is-promise property. I think the command for that was called `npm remove is-promise`, but I am not sure.

But I am pretty sure that your package.json needs a fix :)
Reply if it didn't work, I'll try to find a different way-around then.

Answer (score 0):

If that solution doesn't work try installing node version 12.12.0 and running create-react-app again.

There are issues with the promise dependency being worked on at the moment. [Issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8897)

Answer (score 0):

**Do not downgrade your node version**. Downgrading was a temporary solution, as for now, this issue is fixed with 2.2.2 version of is-promise package. If you still experience problems creating new CRA, consider `npm install -g --force create-react-app`

If even then bug is still present, please comment your issue to this [github issue](https://github.com/then/is-promise/issues/20)