# error in creating react project by npx create-react-app myapp

Tags: npm, yarnpkg, npx

I saw many articles that similar to my problem like these
[npx create react-app command doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56346019/npx-create-react-app-command-doesnt-work) ,
[command "npx create-react-app project" not generating project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61429682/command-npx-create-react-app-project-not-generating-project) but no one solved mine.

When I wrote npx create-react-app myapp this error happen

> error An unexpected error occurred:
>   "C:\Users\alothman\AppData\Local\Yarn\Cache\v6\npm-p-limit-2.2.2-61279b67721f5287aa1c13a9a7fbbc48c9291b1e-integrity\node_modules\p-limit\.yarn-metadata.json:
>   Unexpected token \u0000 in JSON at position 0".

[image]
and this attaching file was appeared (yarn-error)

https://drive.google.com/file/d/17cOAb2rrS-r9uSUEGvDU1-CAnTukDYFI/view?usp=sharing

hope you help me
thank you

Comment: Have you tried running `yarn cache clean`? This looks like an issue with a corrupted cache.

Comment: yess, it works thank you so much